# CannotPullContainerError when trying to pull from a private docker repository in AWS Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run a multi-container docker build, and have run into issues with getting my private docker repository to work.

I have created a "dockercfg.json" file to hold my auth, thus:

```
{"https://index.docker.io/v1/":{"auth":"59...22","email":"ra...@...com"}}
```

and uploaded it to an S3 bucket in the same region as my EB instance, and created a Dockerrun.aws.json file thus:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "authentication": {
    "bucket": "hayl-docker",
    "key": "dockercfg.json"
  },
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "hayl",
      "image": "raddishiow/hayl-docker:uwsgi",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 443,
          "containerPort": 443
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but I keep getting errors like this:

> STOPPED, Reason CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for raddishiow/hayl-docker, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

I've verified that AWS is able to access the "docker cfg.json" file. I'm not sure it's using the credentials though...

I have changed the docker repository to public briefly and it pulls successfully, but that's not an option really as the image contains sensitive code that I don't want in the public domain.

The auth token I'm using was created using the docker website, as my local docker config file doesn't store my login details...
I've tried manually base64 encoding my password as docker would do to store it in the config file, but this doesn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been tearing my hair out for days over this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the "auth" token must be generated from your username and password encoded into base64, in the format "username:password".